# how do I call an image that I have read on pushbutton1 to pushbutton4 on the matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I do an imread image on pushbutton1 to take a picture, and will do the encryption process on that image using pushbutton4, but I have difficulty calling the image from pushbutton1 to pushbutton4, please give me a solution to this problem. thanks

i tried this on pushbutton1

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in enkrip future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[namafile1, formatfile1] = uigetfile({'*.png':'*.jpg':'*.bmp'}, 'Pilih Gambar');
image1 = imread([formatfile1, namafile1]);
guidata(hObject, handles);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(image1); 
handles.img1 = image1;
```

and i call the image like this on pushbutton4

```
a = handles.img1;
```

and the result like this

```
Error in untitled1>pushbutton4_Callback (line 137)
a = handles.img1;
```

please give me a solution to this problem. thanks

Comment: Move the line `guidata(hObject, handles)` to the end of `pushbutton1` callback. For good practice and stable, you also better call `handles = guidata(hObject)` at start of `pushbutton4` callback, or insert it on the callback definition.

Comment: well, i try your suggestion and work perfectly, thanks bro